# get value of datalist in javascript after user changes value

Tags: javascript, html-datalist

I have a datalist on an order form and the user selects or enters in the value they want. Everything works fine **IF** the user does not go back and change the value originally selected or entered in the datalist input.

If the user changes the value by typing in a new value I can get the correct value **but** if they double click and clear the field so that they can reactivate the datalist selector and pick from the datalist selector then I cannot seem to get the new value.

I have tried to add an EventListener to no avail

```
document.getElementById(height).addEventListener("click", function(){ document.getElementById(height).value; });
```

HTML

```
<input style="width:100%" list="height" id="height_0" onChange="updatePrice(this.id);">
<datalist id="height">
<option value="2.00">
<option value="4.00">
<option value="6.00">
<option value="8.00">
<option value="10.00">
</datalist>
```

javascript

```
function updatePrice(entityLine){
var targetCell = entityLine.split("_");
var theRow = targetCell[1];

var height = "height_" + theRow;
var height = document.getElementById(height).value;
console.log(height);
}
```

Comment: The `onChange` works for me, in Chrome. What is the `addEventListener` part for?

Comment: I agree just tried it in Chrome and everything works its must be a MS Edge issue. The add event listener was a stab at trying another approach.

Comment: THANKS for pointing out Chrome now I know its isolated to a browser.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `document.getElementById('height').value` - note `height` as a string not variable.

Same when adding an event listener.

Comment: height IS a variable as used in the script "height" as in the datalist is a string. I tried it both ways and it must be a variable because then id's would duplicate as I add lines to the order form hence the underscore 0 -  "_0" which denotes the 1st line. So the input is unique. BTW this looks to be an MS Edge issue as it works in Chrome